# Repeating http.post a specified number of times (changing the URL each time)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm having trouble thinking of the correct way to repeat/loop an Angular2(4) http.post request a specified(X) number of times.

Let me give an example of what I hope to achieve. I have the following http.post:

```
this.http.post(`http://url.com/param/name01`, dbJson, options)
```

What I need to do is use a single observable stream to post to an API X amount of times, changing the name parameter each time. I **don't** want to hard-code it like this:

```
this.http.post(`http://url.com/param/name01`, body, options)
.switchMap(() => this.http.post(`http://url.com/param/name02`, body, options)
.switchMap(() => this.http.post(`http://url.com/param/name03`, body, options)
```

Could anyone please shed some light on the best way to use observables to get the result I'm after?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you create an observable from the subscriber?

Comment: Do you want to send it in sequence?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `forkJoin` it'll loop up all requests

```
myNameRequest(): Observable<any> {
 let requests: any[] = [];
 let names: string[] = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
 return Observable.forkJoin(names.map(name => this.http.post(`http://url.com/param/${name}`, body, options)))
}
```

If you have to perform any action after every requests or all requests you can do it in map/subscribe here you can learn about it

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs
https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables-and-concurrent-data-loading

Answer (score 1):

Use concat if you need to execute one request after another. You can create an array of observables with your params and use spread operator to pass them to concat.

```
let names = ['name01', 'name02', 'name03'];

let obs$ 
    = names.map(name=>Rx.Observable.of('path' + name));

Rx.Observable.concat(...obs$)
  .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```